# Django Ignore string after PK in URL

Tags: django, regex, django-urls

product urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
]
```

Currently my url looks like this `http://127.0.0.1:8001/product/11/`
However I want to also append the slug of the product. `http://127.0.0.1:8001/product/11/example-slug/`

But it shouldn't matter what the string is behind it, it should just use the pk in order to display the page. It should ignore the string after `/11/` how can I do that?

Comment: Can you add your `ProductDetailView` ?

Comment: Ignoring the slug could be bad for SEO, because search engines will see the same content on `/product/11/example-slug/` and `/product/11/other-slug/`. To avoid this, Stack Overflow redirects to the real slug, e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445649/made-up-slug` will be redirected to the URL with the correct slug for this question.

Comment: other-slug is never linked though, but I understand yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url:

```
path(<int:pk>/<str:xxx>', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail')
```

The view side should look like:

```
   def getproduct(request,pk,xxx):

       the_product= Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

But you should note that if a user changes the string part of the url, the user will still be able to see the page.